# ImportError: No module named <module_name> with pybind11 on MacOS

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am trying to import C++ module created using pybind11 to python script.
The directory structure is:

pybind_test:

```
    main.cpp
    build
    CMakeLists.txt
    test.py
    pybind11 (github repo clone)
```

It builds successfully and the file `module_name.cpython-39-darwin.so` is created. However when running test.py I get:

```
File "../test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from build.module_name import *
ImportError: No module named build.module_name
```

My CMakeLists file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4...3.18)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
project(pybindtest)
add_subdirectory(pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(module_name main.cpp)
```

How would I import this module into python like a normal python module?

Comment: I added my test.py file to build directory where the module was created and it seems to work now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, the compiled library must be in a route (in terms of file path) reachable by the Python executable (which you achieved by moving `test.py` to the build directory, where your compiled library is).
You could also move the compiled library to your Python's `site-packages` folder, where other modules are stored.

Comment: Do you mean `root` instead of `route`?

Comment: @JörgBrüggmann No, I mean a _route_, a _directory_, e.g. `/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages`